# In Vega lite (Deneb) how do I apply a parameter list of regression types to a calculated regression line

Tags: powerbi, regression, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I have created a "poly" regression line for a scatterplot in vega lite similar to the below.

I have also created a parameter list, listing the types of regression (linear, log, etc.)

However, I am unable to correctly map the list so that I am able to switch between different types of regression calcs. So I am looking for some advice.

[image: scatterplot with regression]

In the below code, I have tried replacing:
"method": "poly",

with

"method": {"expr": "regressionline"}

where "regressionline" is the name of my parameter list, but I dont think it is correct.

I was wondering if it is actually possible, and if there is another method.

[image]

Many thanks

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "regressionline",
      "value": "linear",
      "bind": {
        "input": "radio",
        "options": [
          "linear",
          "log",
          "exp",
          "pow",
          "quad",
          "poly"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "rect",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "bin": {"maxbins": 20},
          "field": "Total Ref Estimate - RF",
          "title": "Total Estimate"
        },
        "y": {
          "bin": {"maxbins": 10},
          "field": "Premarket % Costs",
          "title": "Premarket % Costs"
        },
        "color": {
          "aggregate": "count",
          "scale": {
            "scheme": "goldgreen"
          },
          "legend": {
            "direction": "horizontal",
            "gradientLength": 120,
            "orient": "none",
            "legendX": 500,
            "legendY": 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "tooltip": true,
        "color": "white",
        "stroke": "black",
        "strokeWidth": 0.5,
        "size": 25
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Total Ref Estimate - RF",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "format": "$.1s",
            "labelFontSize": 10
          },
          "scale": {
            "domain": [0, 70000000]
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Premarket % Costs",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
          "axis": {
            "format": ".0%",
            "labelFontSize": 10
          }
        },
        "xOffset": {
          "field": "External ID"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "firebrick",
        "strokeWidth": 2.5,
        "strokeDash": [1, 4]
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "regression": "Premarket % Costs",
          "on": "Total Ref Estimate - RF",
          "method": "poly",
          "extent": [1000000, 30000000]
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Total Ref Estimate - RF",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Premarket % Costs",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "regression": "Premarket % Costs",
          "on": "Total Ref Estimate - RF",
          "method": "poly",
          "extent": [1000000, 30000000],
          "params": true
        },
        {
          "calculate": "'R²: '+format(datum.rSquared, '.2f')",
          "as": "R2"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "color": "firebrick",
        "x": "width",
        "align": "right",
        "y": -5
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "type": "nominal",
          "field": "R2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Gerard - can you post a full spec? Would you be prepared to do this in Vega? Thanks

Comment: Hi Davide, Thanks, I added the spec to the original question. Vega should be fine if it is the only way to execute it. Thanks again,

Comment: Thanks. Can you upload the .pbix somewhere or share the sample data?

Comment: Thanks, I have exported a copy of the data from that visual as the pbix file has some other work related info. Let me know if this is sufficient
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FAwjChqQhTXebYxcqkp7BTtT0lA5BNkj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me.

"method": {"signal": "regressionline"},

The schema throws a validation error (as VL doesn't support signals explicitly) but this does work and I can successfully switch between linear, quad and poly. Not sure about the validity of the other methods as I haven't looked at linear regressions in a while.

Comment: Thank you Davide, that works!

As you say, it highlights a minor error, but the functionaiity works. Although the dataset itself doesnt really support this so much, it was more just having the concept of being able to select different types of regression.

Again, many thanks, you are a star!
Regards